# LXD with no internet

Tags: lxd, container

Is there a way to create and launch a LXD container using a local image rather than requiring an internet connection?  All the documentation and how-tos I've been able to find are based on having an internet connection and pulling an image from some remote store.

I would like to be able to put a compatible image on my local filesystem and then build containers from that without having to have any external internet connectivity at all.

Comment: [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd)

I will admit, I hadn't looked at this in a while, it seems that has changed and this may well be exactly the very simple answer I was looking for.

Comment: It is covered in detail here - https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/ , specifically `lxc image import \<file\> --alias my-alias` under the "Manually importing an image" section.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks, I think that may be what I was looking for.  trying it out now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @bodhi.zazen.

Indeed, it is covered at [getting-started-cli](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/) but the other clue was further in at [github](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/image-handling.md)

So the answer is in the following steps:

```
wget http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz
wget http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-lxd.tar.xz
lxc image import xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-lxd.tar.xz rootfs xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.xz --alias SomeAlias
lxc launch SomeAlias MyMachine
```

That gets me to the point where I can create a local image store and either import the images from a local server or copy them to the node and import them directly from the node's filesystem.